# Is it possible in Zeppelin to restrict a user from creating notes?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

Basically, as an Admin, I want some users to only be able to run a specific note, and not only that, I also want to restrict their ability to create any new notes. Is this possible to do in Zeppelin?

Answer (score 1):

For running specfic notebooks you can define security controls at a notebook level. Details can be found here - https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.6.5/bk_zeppelin-component-guide/content/config-access-control-notes.html

For controlling access as to who should be able to create notebooks there is no such feature currently. There is an active JIRA bug for this requirement - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZEPPELIN-3053?jql=project%20%3D%20ZEPPELIN%20AND%20text%20~%20%22notebook%20creation%22

Apart from this there is a feature of Public vs Private where users can set notebooks to be private such that no one else can have access.